# jwt coming back from server but not saving in cookie

Tags: reactjs, jwt

Reciving back jwt as httpOnly cookie but it doesnot get saved in browser cookie

[Reciving back jwt Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubSpQ.png)
[But not get saved in cookie Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xQN7.png)

```
async function onLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = await axios.post(
        `${url}/user/login`,
        {
          username,
          password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        // Request made and server responded
        alert(
          `Error (${error.response.status}):\n${error.response.data.error}`
        );
      } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        console.log("response not recieved from server");
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        alert("Error", error.message);
      }
    }
  }
```